# SQLite Query a range of entries in interval

Tags: android, sqlite, pagination, android-sqlite

I would like to implement a SQL-Query that gives me a range of entries. Example:

```
public List<Entry> getEntries(int lowerValue, int upperValue){
//Select upper - lower entries.
}

getEntries(0, 20) --> First 20 Entries
getEntries(21, 40) --> Entry 21 to 40
getEntries(12, 200) --> Entry 12 to 200
```

At the moment I get all entries like this:

```
public List<Log> getLogs(){
        List<Log> list = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE 1";

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move to the first row in your results
        c.moveToFirst();

        //Position after the last row means the end of the results
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")) != null) {
                int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                int type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
                long date = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
                int refId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("refId"));
                String extra = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("extra"));

                list.add(new Log(id, type, date, refId, extra));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return list;
    }
```

I know there is a LIMIT clause, but that starts always from the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the combination of LIMIT and OFFSET

You could use

```
LIMIT <skip>, <count>
```

or

```
LIMIT <count> OFFSET <skip>
```

So some examples would be

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE type=1 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0"
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE type=1 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20"
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE type=1 LIMIT 20 OFFSET 40"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great. Can you help with this too?`I get this error when I try to order my entries:
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY _id DESC WHERE 1 LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0

Comment: Yeah.  I should have caught that before answering, but you need to set the WHERE to compare a column.  So something like `WHERE type=1`.

Comment: No that already worked before. But when I try to order by ID I got this error!

Comment: Try placing `ORDER BY _id DESC` at the end of the statement.  If memory serves that's a requirement.